# How to send a value from one JSP page to another for each loop without a form?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Tried using session and it doesn't work.

I am uploading data from an external database and displaying them on my page. All the Strings are loading fine and images too but I get the same image (last image in database row) instead of different images each time I loop. I need a way to pass my "id" value from one page to another to be able to construct my SQL query directed to the correct id.

I have tried by using a simple class with a static String and store/change its value on each iteration of the loop so I can call it anywhere. 
I have tried using sessions by setting its attribute on each iteration.

Tried printing the value of both these methods and they only return the value of 19 once (id of last image row).

I have also tried using a hidden input and setting its value and try to get that value at image.jsp. This doesn't work as I am not using a form.

Thus how can I send the updated id value from the first page to image.jsp each time I loop?

First Page

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

<%
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/dbname";
    String dbUser = "";
    String dbPass = "";
    Connection conn;


    try{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset =
                statement.executeQuery("select image, name, age, gender, contact, description, id from driver");

        while(resultset.next()) {
            session.setAttribute("userid", resultset.getString(7)); //trying with sessions
            TempClass.idValue = resultset.getString(7); //trying with a static String value
%>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="k-cust_box">
                <h3><%= resultset.getString(2) %></h3>
                <hr>
                <input name="secret" value="<%= resultset.getString(7) %>"  type="hidden"> <!-- Trying with hidden input value -->
                <img class="k-profile-img" src="image.jsp" height="100px" border="1" style="float: left; overflow: hidden" width="33%">
                <div class="k-driver-inner-box">
                    <h5>Age: <%= resultset.getString(3) %></h5>
                    <h5>Gender: <%= resultset.getString(4) %></h5>
                    <h5>Contact: <%= resultset.getString(5) %></h5>
                </div>
                <h5 class="k-fl-lt"><%= resultset.getString(6) %></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
<%}
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
        </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

image.jsp

```
<body>
<%
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/dbname";
    String dbUser = "";
    String dbPass = "";
    Connection conn;
    byte[] pict = null;

    Object id = session.getAttribute("userid"); //trying to get session id and returns 19 only once. 
    String userid = request.getParameter("secret"); //trying to get hidden input value - this always returns null. Expected. 
    String staticId = TempClass.idValue;  //trying to get static value and returns 19 only once. 

    try{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset =
                statement.executeQuery("select image from driver where id = '" + id + "'"); //this id value has to change on each loop to be able to load different images. 
        response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        while(resultset.next()) {
            Blob bl = resultset.getBlob(1);
            pict = bl.getBytes(1,(int)bl.length());
        }
        OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
        o.write(pict);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
</body>
```

Comment: Try `src="image.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString(7)%>"`. In `image.jsp`, `String id = request.getParameter("id");`

Comment: @Satya How does image.jsp capture this id value? Do I need to set anything new at image.jsp?

Comment: @Satya Perfect works. Thanks.

Comment: @Satya, you better put your comment as an answer and claim your reward ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In First Page, `img` tag,

```
src="image.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString(7)%>"
```

In `image.jsp`,

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

Comment: @JasSy Good work. You are welcome. If it resolve your issue accept it as answer.